# How should I structure a class heirarchy consisting of interface implementors with children?

Tags: oop, inheritance, architecture

I work on software that takes an enormous number of inputs and then designs machinery automatically. Right now I am building a reporting system that provides complicated pdf reports on the performance, construction, and design of this machinery. This machinery has a number of distinct parts that have a number of standard types, (example: the part is "Engine", and a given subtype could be "2 Cylinder"); the design is all parametric and the subtypes are different enough to merit their own classes. All these parts have dimension measurements, and I have to provide reports in both IP and SI units. I need ideas for how to structure a class hierarchy that makes sense and is easy to work with in the rest of the code I will write. The catch is in unit conversions. Some parts of the Engine are universal and will always exist and be implemented the same way regardless of subclass, so it needs conversion methods, but other fields are not universal, so the base classes need conversion methods too.

Let's go with the Engine example. Here's something like what I've got right now. I have a base abstract class representing the Engine, implementing an `IConvertible` interface which means that the part is able to be converted from IP units to SI units. The subclass, `TwoCylinderEngine` inherits from Engine and overrides the Conversion methods of the Engine class, but does not implement `IConvertible` itself. I should mention I have a Measurement class that handles unit conversions, so the implementation of that part is irrelevant to my problem.

```
public abstract class Engine : IConvertible {

    Measurement someMeasurement;

    public void ConvertToIP(){
        BaseConvertToIP();
    }

    public void ConvertToSI(){
        BaseConvertToSI();
    }

    public void BaseConvertToIP(){
        someMeasurement = someMeasurement.ConvertTo("some IP Unit");
    }

    public void BaseConvertToSI(){
        someMeasurement = someMeasurement.ConvertTo("some SI Unit");
    }
}

public class TwoCylinderEngine: Engine{

    Measurement someOtherMeasurement;

    public override void ConvertToIP(){
        BaseConvertToIP();
        someOtherMeasurement = someOtherMeasurement.ConvertTo("some IP Unit");
    }

    public override void ConvertToSI(){
        BaseConvertToSI();
        someOtherMeasurement = someOtherMeasurement.ConvertTo("some SI Unit");
    }
}

public interface IConvertible
{
    void ConvertToIP();
    void ConvertToSI();
    void BaseConvertToIP();
    void BaseConvertToSI();
}
```

This construct works well for me, but I am unsettled by the need to make `BaseConvertToIP()` and `BaseConvertToSI()` public. I wish there was a way to declare protected interface methods for this kind of circumstance, but I understand that goes against the idea of what an interface is in the first place. I'm not sure what kind of relationship this thing fits into as far as OOP goes. Any ideas?

Comment: Not really sure what it is you are attempting to do here. From the code you've posted it seems clear that the IP and SI units should be properties of the measurement and not the engine. Why not implement the `ConvertToIP` and `ConvertToSI` in the `Measurement` class itself?

Comment: Measurements don't know whether the units they are in are IP or SI. Even if they did, the ConvertToIP and ConvertToSI methods are needed because a lot of time people are able to print reports either in IP or SI, so I need to be able to convert all the measurements in the parts classes at once. I don't want everywhere to have such intimate knowledge of my parts classes that they can list all the measurements within them and convert them one by one. And I don't want to go hunting for those bits of code whenever the part changes and gains or loses a measurement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for the question in the first place. I thought I'd tried this, but it seems not. The issue I had lay in the public nature of `BaseConvertTo` methods, which I didn't like. The solution is to not have those methods at all. Instead, just have virtual `ConvertTo` methods in the base class and then those can be called with `base.ConvertTo` in the derived classes. This fixes the one issue I had with the class hierarchy.

```
public abstract class Engine : IConvertible {

    Measurement someMeasurement;

    public virtual void ConvertToIP(){
        someMeasurement.ConvertTo("Some IP Unit");
    }

    public virtual void ConvertToSI(){
        someMeasurement.ConvertTo("Some SI Unit");
    }
}

public class TwoCylinderEngine: Engine{

    Measurement someOtherMeasurement;

    public override void ConvertToIP(){
        base.ConvertToIP();
        someOtherMeasurement = someOtherMeasurement.ConvertTo("some IP Unit");
    }

    public override void ConvertToSI(){
        base.ConvertToSI();
        someOtherMeasurement = someOtherMeasurement.ConvertTo("some SI Unit");
    }
}

public interface IConvertible
{
    void ConvertToIP();
    void ConvertToSI();
}
```

This achieves what I want. The question title is still relevant I think. It's just that the answer is a lot simpler than I was thinking it would be.